# Lodash get repetition count with the object itself

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of objects like:

```
[  {
"username": "user1",
"profile_picture": "TESTjpg",
"id": "123123",
"full_name": "User 1"
}, {
"username": "user2",
"profile_picture": "TESTjpg",
"id": "43679144425",
"full_name": "User 2"
}, {
"username": "user2",
"profile_picture": "TESTjpg",
"id": "43679144425",
"full_name": "User 2"
} ]
```

I want to get:

```
[  {
"username": "user1",
"profile_picture": "TESTjpg",
"id": "123123",
"full_name": "User 1",
"count": 1
}, {
"username": "user2",
"profile_picture": "TESTjpg",
"id": "43679144425",
"full_name": "User 2",
"count": 2
} ]
```

I've used lodash a.k.a. underscore for this method but failed to process it.

```
var uniqueComments =  _.chain(comments).uniq(function(item) { return item.from.id; }).value();
    var resComment = [];
    _.forEach(uniqueComments, function(unco) {
        unco.count = _.find(comments, function(comment) {
            return unco.id === comment.id
        }).length;

        resComment.push(unco);
    });
```

The result should be in `resComment`.

**EDIT**: Updated array of objects.

Comment: You don't give us the source data, otherwise I could have given you an even shorter solution that looks a bit nicer. But, consider this: _(comments).uniq('item.from.id').countBy('name)

Comment: I've updated the question @EngineerDollery

Comment: lodash and underscore are two different libraries where lodash covers most of underscore methods in same signature and provides even more in more performant way. lodash is not "also known as" underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into using `_.reduce()`, since that's what you're doing--reducing the given array into a (potentially) smaller array containing a different sort of object.

Using `_.reduce()`, you'd do something like this:

```
var resComment = _.reduce(comments, function(mem, next) {
    var username = next.username;
    var existingObj = _.find(mem, function(item) { return item.username === username; });
    existingObj ? existingObj.count++ : mem.push(_.extend(next, {count: 1}));
    return mem;
}, []);
```

And here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/pwsz5sj3/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty close using [countBy](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#countBy):

```
var counts = _.countBy(uniqueComments, 'name');
```

We could go further, using _.keys() to iterate through the counts object and transforming them into your final result set, but you can probably achieve that bit easily enough using _keys.

Comment: Can you give me a more generalized solution?